# Как выводить сообщения вида echo в div?

Tags: php, javascript, echo

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы сообщения вида `echo` выводились в div? Заранее спасибо! Сообщение посылается обработчиком. Ниже пример скрипта, который возвращает значение.

```
if($inserted_id > 0) { 
            echo "uploaded file: " . $fileName;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть много различных методов (два по крайней мере точно есть =) ). Первый заключается в банальном выводе HTML-кода в блок, который нужно заполнить. Например:

```
<div>
<?php echo('text')?>
</div>
```

Второй способ одновременно и удобный и "нубский", но тем не менее его все часто используют, включая меня). Способ заключается в выводе JavaScript кода в любую точку страницы. Далее обо всем позаботится яваскрипт:

**Где-то на странице:**

```
<?php
$text = "<b>BOB</b>";
echo("<script>$('#somediv').html('$text')</script>");
?>
```

"Нубство" данного способа заключается в том, что JavaScript получается разбросанным по всей странице, что ни есть хорошо. Из этого следует, что где-то внизу страницы нужно выделить отдельную секцию, блок для подобных вставок явасрипта.

Comment: ну в принципе да, сохраняем текст в переменную, а потом в нужном месте ее выводим...

Answer (score 2):

```
if($inserted_id > 0) { 
    echo "<div>uploaded file: ".$fileName."</div>";
}
```