# Как вывести текст в конкретный элемент html с помощью php? Почему так, как я пробую сделать не работает?

Tags: php, form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
     body, html {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
     }
     div#sidebar {
         float: left;
         width: 300px;
         height: 1000px;
         background-color: #000;
         color: #fff;
     }
     div#sidebar p {
         text-align: center;
     }
     div#center {
         float: left;
         width: 1218px;
         height: 1000px;
         background-color: #efefef;
     }
     form {
         width: 500px;
         margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
     }
     label {
         width: 200px;
         float: left;
         margin-bottom: 10px;
     }
     input[type="text"] {
         margin-bottom: 10px;
     }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
    <div id="center">
     <form action="<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>" method="POST">
      <label for="user">Введите имя пользователя:</label>
      <input type="text" name="user" id="user"><br>
      <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
      <input type="text" name="email"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
     </form>
    </div>
    <?php
     if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
         if (!empty($_POST["user"]) && !empty($_POST["email"])) {
             $user = $_POST["user"];
             $email = $_POST["email"];
             echo ("<script>$('#sidebar').html('<p>$user<br>$email</p>')</script>");

         } 
     }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

После заполнения формы хочу вывести имя пользователя и e-mail в левый сайд бар с помощью echo ("....") и почему-то не работает.
Как исправить эту проблему ?

Comment: попробуйте запихнуть скрипт в `$(document).onload`

Comment: Зачем вы через JS это делаете?

Comment: @DaemonHK в интернете наткнулся только на такой способ. Как я понял через PHP это сделать есть только один способ - вывести напрямую с помощью echo прямо в элемент html, но в  этой ситуации этот способ не подходит

Comment: @JustLearn почему же? Сначала добавляете, потом на js делаете что нужно

Comment: @DaemonHK вы знаете другой способ на PHP?

Comment: @DaemonHK в смысле? Я не понял, можете пожалуйста пример кода дать?

Comment: @JustLearn ответил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
   if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
       if (!empty($_POST["user"]) && !empty($_POST["email"])) {
           $user = $_POST["user"];
           $email = $_POST["email"];
       } 
   }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
         body, html {
             margin: 0;
             padding: 0;
         }
         div#sidebar {
             float: left;
             width: 300px;
             height: 1000px;
             background-color: #000;
             color: #fff;
         }
         div#sidebar p {
             text-align: center;
         }
         div#center {
             float: left;
             width: 1218px;
             height: 1000px;
             background-color: #efefef;
         }
         form {
             width: 500px;
             margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
         }
         label {
             width: 200px;
             float: left;
             margin-bottom: 10px;
         }
         input[type="text"] {
             margin-bottom: 10px;
         }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="sidebar">
            <p>Hello World</p>
            <?php
            if ( !empty($user) && !empty($email) ) {
            ?>
            <p> <?= $user ?> <br> <?= $email ?> </p>
            <?php 
              } 
            ?>
        </div>
        <div id="center">
         <form action="<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>" method="POST">
          <label for="user">Введите имя пользователя:</label>
          <input type="text" name="user" id="user"><br>
          <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
          <input type="text" name="email"><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
         </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: У меня не работает

Comment: Что именно не работает, можно подробней? Если посмотреть код стараницы то js добавляется то данные в нём верные стоят?

Comment: Не выводится имя пользователя и email в сайд баре под Hello World

Comment: Если посмотреть код стараницы то js добавляется и данные в нём верные стоят?

Comment: @JustLearn библиотека JQ подключена?

Comment: @InDevX да, в коде страницы добавляется

Comment: поправил ответ, попробуйте так - без js

Comment: @nicolaa нет. Я вообще на JS никогда не писал. Я погуглил и нашел на стэк оферфлоу тему, где предлагали вариант для вывода текста в html код с помощью JS. Вот топик: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/141160/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0-echo-%D0%B2-div/141215

Comment: @InDevX о! Спасибо большое!))

Answer (score 1):

Зачем тут JS?

```html
<?php
//Работа с данными должна быть ДО отрисовки страницы
$data = "Hello World";
if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST["user"]) && !empty($_POST["email"])) {
  $data = $_POST["user"]."<br />".$_POST["email"];
} 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
     body, html {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
     }
     div#sidebar {
         float: left;
         width: 300px;
         height: 1000px;
         background-color: #000;
         color: #fff;
     }
     div#sidebar p {
         text-align: center;
     }
     div#center {
         float: left;
         width: 1218px;
         height: 1000px;
         background-color: #efefef;
     }
     form {
         width: 500px;
         margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
     }
     label {
         width: 200px;
         float: left;
         margin-bottom: 10px;
     }
     input[type="text"] {
         margin-bottom: 10px;
     }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <p><?=$data?></p>
    </div>
    <div id="center">
     <form action="<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>" method="POST">
      <label for="user">Введите имя пользователя:</label>
      <input type="text" name="user" id="user"><br>
      <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
      <input type="text" name="email"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
     </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Я разобрался

Comment: @JustLearn не за что)